# Need Help Studying Running Times

Tags: binary-search, performance, insertion-sort

At the moment, I'm studying for a final exam for a Computer Science course. One of the questions that will be asked is most likely a question on how to combine running times, so I'll give an example.

I was wondering, if I created a program that preprocessed inputs using Insertion Sort, and then searched for a value "X" using Binary Search, how would I combine the running times to find the best, worst, and average case time complexities of the over-all program?

For example...
Insertion Sort
Worst Case O(n^2)
Best Case O(n)
Average Case O(n^2)
Binary Search
Worst Case O(logn)
Best Case O(1)
Average Case O(logn)

Would the Worst case be O(n^2 + logn), or would it be O(n^2), or neither?
Would the Best Case be O(n)?
Would the Average Case be O(nlogn), O(n+logn), O(logn), O(n^2+logn), or none of these?

I tend to over-think solutions, so if I can get any guidance on combining running times, it would be much appreciated.

Thank you very much.

Comment: perhaps another angle helps: http://eternallyconfuzzled.com/arts/jsw_art_bigo.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You usually don't "combine" (as in add) the running times to determine the **overall efficiency class** rather, you take the one that takes the longest for each worst, average, and best case.

So if you're going to perform insertion sort and then do a binary search after to find an element X in an array, the worst case is O(n^2) and the best case is O(n) -- all from insertion sort since it takes the longest.

Comment: Okay, great. Just to make sure I'm following you correctly, will that be true regardless of the size of the set of inputs or number of searches for x?

Comment: But the running time for the overall case depends on how many searches are made. If fewer than n^2 searches are made, then the overall time is definitely proportional to n^2. But if an infinite number of searches are performed, the overall run time is O(M log n), where `M` is the number of searches. So one could say that the amortized run time of the sort-and-search is O(M log n).

Comment: @Jim Mischel Thank you very much! I'm just wondering where you got that knowledge? In this situation, I would like to assume that the searches are much greater in number than the size of the input.

Comment: Also, in that case, wouldn't it be Θ(M log n), if I assumed the searches were always greater than n^2?

Answer (score 0):

Based on my limited study, (we haven't reached Amortization so this might be where Jim has the rest correct), but basically you just go based on whoever is slowest of the overall algorithm.

This seems to be a good book on the subject of Algorithms (I haven't got much to compare to): 
[http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Algorithms-Third-Thomas-Cormen/dp/0262033844/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1303528736&sr=8-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262033844)

Also MIT has a full course on the Algorithms on their site here is the link for that too!
http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-046j-introduction-to-algorithms-sma-5503-fall-2005/

I've actually found it helpful, it might not answer specifically your question, but I think it will help get you more confident seeing some of the topics explained a few times.